# When switching to another page, the application crashes

Tags: android, android-studio

When you start the main screen, the application crashes after 5 seconds? The main screen should go to the second page of the application, but it does not work.
Presented by 2 MainActivity

//MainActivity

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Thread thread = new Thread() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(5);
                    Intent intent2 = new Intent(MainActivity.this, MainActivity1.class);
                    startActivity(intent2);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        };

        thread.start();
    }}
```

//MainActivity1

```
public class MainActivity1 extends AppCompatActivity {
    private RecyclerView recyclerView;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main1);
        Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.list);
        LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this, RecyclerView.VERTICAL, false);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);
        recyclerView.addItemDecoration(new DividerItemDecoration(this, DividerItemDecoration.VERTICAL));

        final Adapter adapter = new Adapter();
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

        FloatingActionButton fab = findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                NoteDetailsActivity.start(MainActivity1.this, null);
            }
        });

        MainViewModel mainViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(MainViewModel.class);
        mainViewModel.getNoteLiveData().observe(this, new Observer<List<Note>>() {
            @Override
            public void onChanged(List<Note> notes) {
                adapter.setItems(notes);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

I tried to describe it in a different way in MainActivity

Comment: Hello. What is the error message in Logcat ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this code in `MainActivity`

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        
        Handler handler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());
        handler.postDelayed(() -> {
            Intent intent2 = new Intent(MainActivity.this, MainActivity1.class);
            startActivity(intent2);
        }, 5000);        
    }
}
```